# Dynamically Add gridview and its columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In .aspx.cs page, how can i create gridview and add columns ,add  boundfiled . Here i am attaching .aspx code to create gridview, so as it is how can i create in code behind?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="GID" DataField="GID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Subject" DataField="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Category" />      
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Dx" DataField="Dx" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Guidelines" DataField="Guidelines" />      
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="FilePath" HeaderText="Image" ItemStyle-Height="25px" ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Well, try to create datatable, and bind it to gridview, set auto generated columns property to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it try

```
       BoundField test = new BoundField();
        test.DataField = "New DATAfield Name";
        test.Headertext = "New Header";
        CustomersGridView.Columns.Add(test);
```